# Finding the Snakeskin Purse?

Tags: dragons-dogma

There is a quest named "A Lost Cause" where you must find a snakeskin purse. But without any quest marker or even a general location, where am I supposed to find this purse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the aqueducts in Gran Soren, there's a gate leading outside. There's a riverside area there. Check the schools of fish there and hopefully you'll find the purse. However, it's possible that the location is random. Regardless, you'll definitely find it in schools of fish.

Comment: Wish I had known this while I still had my PS3 and was still playing DD. That quest is worth quite a bit of exp/gold if I remember correctly.